# Remove Array and its contents with mouse click AS3 Flash CS5.5

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, removechild

I have been trying to do this for two nights now and haven't had any joy, please help if you can...

Simple throwing game with darts and other weapons, what I am trying to do is 
Remove an array and all of its Children when I change weapon,

I feel sure there is a simple snippet of code that will remove all the children and array with no hassle but I haven't yet figured it out, if you know or could suggest anything, I would really appreciate it.

something like "removeArrayAndAllInstances(balls);" if only... 
at the moment I have....(balls is the array in question)

```
 for(var inter:int = balls.length - 1; inter > -1; inter--)
      {
        balls.splice(1);
        balls.splice(1, balls.length);
      }
```

but this docent work for some reason, the array and all of its children are all still on the stage.

I also tried

```
balls[];
```

No luck...

Please don't judge my code I am a novice as I am sure was evident and I know its a disgusting mess, sorry (Its the only way it makes sense to me).

I have tried numerous things, hope someone can help

Thanks in advance.....

```
    var mouseTarget:MovieClip;
var balls:Array = new Array();
var ball:MovieClip = new dart();
var hammers:MovieClip = new hammer();
ball.x = 150;
ball.y = 50;

hammer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hammerweapon);
dart_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dartweapon);

function removealldartsfromstage(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  for(var inter:int = balls.length - 1; inter > -1; inter--)
  {
    balls.splice(1);
    balls.splice(1, balls.length);
  }

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addDart);    
} 
function dartweapon(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addHammer);
    dart_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dartweapon);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addDart);
    //removeChild(balls);

}
function hammerweapon(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addDart);
    dart_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dartweapon);
    //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addDart);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, addHammer);

}


function addHammer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var hammers = new hammer();
    addChild(hammers);
    removeChild(dart_btn);
    addChild(dart_btn);
    dart_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dartweapon);
    balls.splice(10);
}

function addDart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    str.alpha = 0;
    var ball = new dart();
    addChild(ball);
    removeChild(hammer_btn);
    addChild(hammer_btn);
    ball.x = 150;
    ball.y = 50;
    balls.push(ball);
    trace(balls);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkIfHitTest);
    hammer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, removealldartsfromstage);
    function checkIfHitTest(Event)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i<balls.length; i++)
        {
            if (balls[i].dart_point.hitTestObject(eyeleft))
            {
                trace("hitleftbullseye");
                ball.gotoAndStop("hitlefteyeframe");
                Event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.type, checkIfHitTest);
                balls.splice(i, 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `balls.splice(0);` should be enough. Why do you have two calls to `splice` and then that within a loop? `splice` takes the starting index and a `deleteCount` which if you omit defaults to all elements. You can use the `pop` or `shift` methods if you need to remove one item at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your response dirkgently, I did try balls.splice(0);on its own and it didn't work, I have it in a loop as someone suggested it might help, what you see in the code is a result of desperate attempts to get it working, why would balls.splice(0); not work? any ideas?

Comment: Try `array.splice()` i.e. without the index. Or, `array.length = 0`. (I have no idea why it wouldn't work.) Check the size of your array (i.e. it is non-zero). If the first two doesn't work, can you try removing one item at a time by using `pop` within a loop?

Comment: for(var inter:int = balls.length - 1; inter > -1; inter--)
  {
 balls.pop();
  }

Comment: OK I tried the above code and it didn't work, also tried array.splice() and array.length = 0, ahhh I don't know whats going on! is it because of the way I am making the array? Thanks for your help so far, very much appreciated, John

Comment: ... and your `Array` is not empty?

Comment: The Array is not empty,(is there a way of tracing the array amount? trace(array.NumChildren?)) erkmene below has got us a little closer, we have been able to communicate with the array, it just goes away then reappears, also none of the children are removed. thanks for getting back to me dirkently

Answer (score 1):

The balls array is just a storage for ball references. It bears no relation to the stage or the DisplayObjectContainer which they have been added at all. So you have to remove them individually.

This is what I'd do:

```
while(balls.length > 0)
{
    var ball:MovieClip = balls.pop();
    if (ball.parent) // Just to make sure you are referencing the correct container.
    {
        ball.parent.removeChild(ball);
    }
}
```

I can't follow the logic of your game very well. That said, you'd do well to create conatiners for separate group of clips in order to make managing them easier. For example, in the creation stage:

```
var ballContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(ballContainer);
for (var i:int = 0; i < ballLimit; i++)
{
    var ball:Dart = new Dart();
    ballContainer.addChild(ball);
}
```

This way, you can clear them of children all at once:

```
function removeAllChildren(container:Sprite) // Or just DisplayObjectContainer
{
    while(container.numChildren > 0)
    {
        container.removeChild(container.getChildAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you very much erkmene, I think its almost there, the instance on the stage now flashes and reappears and all of the children are also still on the stage, but I think we are getting closer, at least we are clearly communicating with the array at long last Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry I had MOUSE_DOWN, not CLICKED, thats fixed the flash, do you know how I delete the other Children?

Comment: Thanks for your help erkmene, very clear helpful instructions.